# Call controller from aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, function, charts

This is my first time trying to implement a project using MVC, and I am kind of lost.

I have a view, named chart.aspx

and a controller which has the function

```
public ActionResult GetChartImage()
    {
        var key = new Chart(width: 300, height: 300)
            .AddTitle("Employee Chart")
            .AddSeries(
            chartType: "Bubble",
            name: "Employee",
            xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Dave" },
            yValues: new[] { "2", "7", "5", "3" });

        return File(key.ToWebImage().GetBytes(), "image/jpeg");
    }
```

I want to call that from my aspx page, in order to show a chart.

How I can do that?

Comment: You did't call this in your aspx page! have u used razor view?

Comment: No. aspx. I had chose it randomly.... I did not know which of the two was better. Should I change to razor? but how I could make that graph to appear at my page (aspx or razor). I am new to these..

Comment: Wouln't a simple GET request your action work? Like so: `/YourController/GetChartImage`

Comment: @Saravana No. It does not work....

Comment: Do you want to get the result as a file or do you want to embed it in an `img` tag?

Comment: Basically I just want to show a graph of some data. What file do you mean?

Comment: Take a look my answer

Comment: yep ! bcs razor is better than aspx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view add the following:

```
<img src="<%= Html.Action("GetChartImage", "YourControllerName") %>" />
```

Comment: thanks. However this gives me an exception {System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'. ---> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used.
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.get_OutputStream()

Comment: Are you able to get the image by pointing your browser to `http:\\yoursite\YourControllerName\GetChartImage`?

Comment: No my friend. I can't

Answer (score 0):

Try this,Use `Url.action` in your `img` tag `src`

and also need to change `ActionResult` to `FileContentResult` . But it does not a matter .

```
<img  src="@Url.Action("GetChartImage", "YourControllerName")" />
```

Comment: OP is using aspx, not razor :-)

Comment: I asked for that ! and will change to razor